# My ember-simple-auth authenticator cannot call super. Why is that?

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I'm trying to implement an authenticator such that it will let me send a `client_id` with OAuth. In `app/authenticators/oauth-custom.js`:

```
import Authenticator from 'simple-auth-oauth2/authenticators/oauth2';

export default Authenticator.extend({
  makeRequest: (url,  data) => {
    data.client_id = EmberENV.clientId;
    return this._super(url, data);
  }
});
```

This however generate an error when I attempt to sign in:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '_super' of undefined

The source map seem to suggest that `_this` is set to be `undefined`.

```
define('frontend/authenticators/oauth-custom', ['exports', 'simple-auth-oauth2/authenticators/oauth2'], function (exports, Authenticator) {

  'use strict';

  var _this = undefined;

  exports['default'] = Authenticator['default'].extend({
    makeRequest: function makeRequest(url, data) {
      data.client_id = EmberENV.clientId;
      return _this._super(url, data);
    }
  });
});
```

I'm using the current latest ember-cli 0.2.7, ember 1.13.2, ember-simple-auth 0.8.0. What's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused about how the arrow functions work in ES6. Using arrow function means that `this` inside the arrow function body refers to the `this` value of its parent. This works:

```
export default Authenticator.extend({
  makeRequest: function makeRequest(url, data) {
    data.client_id = EmberENV.clientId;
    return this._super(url, data);
  }
});
```